# Do I need a new or a repositioned TV aerial for freeview?

Tags: tv-antenna

One of our tenants would like a TV in their room. The aerial in question hasn't been used for over 10 years, way before the switch over to digital. We don't even know if it still works. I was wondering would we need to have it repositioned in order to receive freeview channels? Or is it a case of sticking on a connector then connecting it to the TV. The actual antenna is just above the window of the room in question so the cable would be quite a short run; a few metres at the most.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using the same antenna for receiving terrestrial broadcasts on my new (digital) TV that I had on my old (analog) TV.

Comment: For those outside the UK, NZ or AU, "Freeview" is largely a marketing term for digital terrestrial television.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antenna should be fine, the frequencies are still the same, it is the format of the information being transmitted that has changed.

If that antenna is to be attached to a TV that hasn't been used for 10 years, odds are good that the TV will require a digital to analog converter box.

Answer (score 1):

Antennae are just metal structures of some form. Short of rust, they don't really wear out. They may be tailored for particular frequencies, however.

With digital TV, the signal isn't as strong as it was with analog, so it helps to have a bigger/better antennae whenever you can.

Anyways, the best way to figure this out is to plug the antennae into a TV (or, as Edwin states, if the TV doesn't have a digital receiver, you'll need a converter box).

If it works, great! If not, you may want to look at getting an HDTV antennae. They're about $50 and depending on your location, may work fine inside the room itself, or could benefit by being up in an attic or the like.

Also, if you happen to be located in a major Television market, and don't live next to a mountain or in a tunnel, you might find that good-ol rabbit ears will work just fine.

ADDENDUM:

I just noticed you use the term 'freeview'. In North America, we refer to TV broadcast over the air waves ('free' TV) as "OTA" or "Over The Air" and is what my answer above refers too.

However, in the UK, 'Freeview' is a specific term for a type of OTA. As far as I can tell, it's pretty much the same, but I don't know if there is a particular device you may need in addition to the receiver and antennae.